# Efficient method of finding database rows that have *one or more* qualities from a list of seven qualities

Tags: php, mysql, search

For this question, I'm looking to see if anyone has a better idea of how to implement what I'm currently planning on implementing (below):

I'm keeping track of a set of images, using a database.  Each image is represented by one row.

I want to be able to search for images, using a number of different search parameters.  One of these parameters involves a search-by-color option.  (The rest of the search stuff is currently working fine.)

Images in this database can contain up to seven colors:

-Red

-Orange

-Yellow

-Green

-Blue

-Indigo

-Violet

Here are some example user queries:

"I want an image that contains red."

"I want an image that contains red and blue."

"I want an image that contains yellow and violet."

"I want an image that contains red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo and violet."

And so on.  Users make this selection through the use of checkboxes in an html form.  They can check zero checkboxes, all seven, and anything in between.

I'm curious to hear what people think would be the most efficient way to perform this database search.

I have two possible options right now, but I feel like there must be something better that I'm not thinking of.

(Option 1)
-For each row, simply have seven additional fields in the database, one for each color.  Each field holds a 1 or 0 (true/false) value, and I SELECT based on whatever the user has checked off.  (I didn't like this solution so much, because it seemed kind of wasteful to add seven additional fields...especially since most pictures in this table will only have 3-4 colors max, though some *could* have up to 7.  So that means I'm storing a lot of zeros.) Also, if I added more searchable colors later on (which I don't think I will, but it's always possible), I'd have to add more fields.

(Option 2)
-For each image row, I could have a "colors" text field that stores space-separated color names (or numbers for the sake of compactness).  Then I could do a fulltext match against search through the fields, selecting rows that contain "red yellow green" (or "1 3 4").  But I kind of didn't want to do fulltext searching because I already allow a keyword search, and I didn't really want to do two fulltext searches per image search. Plus, if the database gets big, fulltext stuff might slow down.

Any better options that I didn't think of?

Thanks!

Side Note: I'm using PHP to work with a MySQL database.

Comment: When you say, "I want an image that contains red", do you you really mean you want an image that contains red and no other color (so to speak)?

Comment: No, in this case I mean that I want any image that contains any red (whether it's [only red], or [red and blue and yellow]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a second table called colors.

```
  colors = (color_id, name)
```

and a relationship table called image_colors.

```
  image_colors = (image_id, color_id)
```

Then in the image_colors table you add a row for each color of each image.

```
 image_colors
 Image_id     Color_id
  1            1
  2            3
  2            4
```

So image 1 has a single color but image 2 has two colors.

To find an image with say color 4 and 5 you can then

```
    select  i.fileName, etc
    from images i JOIN image_colors c ON
         i.image_id = c.image_id
    where
         c.color_id = 4 OR
         c.color_id = 5
```

The advantage of this solution is the ease of querying.

Comment: I like this approach!  And if on the php side, I refer to colors by numbers rather than names, I can even make it one table instead of two.  My only concern would be the potentially large size of the image_colors table.  Do you think I could see a major performance hit with a large number of images?  If, for example, I have 1 Million images, that could mean that I might have (assuming an average of 4 colors per image) 4 Million rows in the image_colors table?  And if I'm doing color = 1 OR color = 5 OR color = 7, do you think that could lead to a slow return?  (Also with more pics over time?)

Comment: MySQL is designed to handle these large tables and has many features such as indexing that can greatly speed up querying. If you are going to query against a certain field all the time then you would usually add an index to the field and that should improve the speeds.

Comment: @Vincent Ramdhanie  Ohhhh yes, haha.  I'm definitely using indexing.  :)  I just didn't know what kinds of slow-downs I'd see, even with indexing, in a Million+ row scenario.

Comment: @Mike CHAR(1) could be better than TINYINT(1)?

Comment: CHAR(1) might be better than int for the colors.

Or not. I can imagine people wanting to search for black, brown, tan, lime green . . . I'm not sure limiting your design to 7 colors will stand up to real-world use.

Comment: @hithere: CHAR(1) can store "R", "O", "Y"--much more friendly than any size integer. But, as I said above, I'm not sure 7 colors will stand up to real-world use.

Comment: @Mike Fortunately, there's no need to worry about the color limitations.  This is a controlled situation anyway.  I chose these colors deliberately, and the images used are solely for this setup.  And wouldn't an indexed search for integers be faster than an indexed search for characters?  Or are the single characters, in addition to taking up less space, treated as if they were numbers?  I'm just thinking that a number comparison is faster than a string comparison.  (That is, if the chars are treated like strings.)

Comment: In the end, I'll go with Vincent Ramdhanie's solution because I think it would result in relatively few database cells (compared to a seven extra column approach), it allows me to use indexes and it's easy to work with for queries.  Thank you to everyone who contributed answers and comments!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the list of colors will never (or very very rarely) change, it is probably more efficient to add 7 additional columns to the images table.  The join and de-duplication for each query that would come out of normalizing them would typically be more expensive than the extra I/O incurred by making the rows wider by 7 fields.

For what it's worth, if you ever get a chance to move to Oracle, [bitmap indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_bitmapped_indexes.htm) are built for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: I guess performance-wise, the seven column approach good, but I didn't like the idea of using up all of that space.  I agree about the JOIN tradeoff too.  You make a good point.  Also, cool stuff with the Oracle bitmap indexes! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store an additional INT field and store 1 number representing a Flags bitwise definition of the colors associated.  When searching you can just execute the same bitwise operation to query for a specific integer value.

Look at Mark Cain's comment on this MySql reference manual page for a good example of what I'm proposing:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: @Tahbaza I had actually considered something that too, but I didn't know how to do any bitwise stuff in the WHERE clause in a query.  Do you know how efficient it is to do something like this (and I'm doing this in more human readable syntax rather than bitwise stuff): WHERE the first digit of the int is 1 and the fifth digit of the int is 1  ?  Actually, is what I suggested even possible?  I'm hoping that I didn't misunderstand what you suggested.

Comment: @HiThere: You get what I'm saying, but I would not do the bitwise operation in SQL, on your screen your criteria will probably be a list of checkboxes.  Just do the bitwise integer calculation in code and pass that as a parameter to your query as part of its where clause.  I would give you an example of the bitwise algorithm but I'm not a php developer.  Here's a link that covers it though http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php.

Comment: @Tahbaza Thanks for the link!  There's one thing I don't quite get though.  While I can see how this method could give me, say, pictures that have only red AND blue, I'm not sure how passing the result of the bitwise integer calculation to the mysql query would give me all pictures that contain either red OR blue.  (And also, do you know what WHERE clause syntax is involved in using a bitwise operation result for comparison? I'm not sure where to go for that part.)

Comment: @HiThere: You would need to save an integer value appropriate to red and blue for a row that should be associated with red and blue (and for every row in your table).  Since you would calculate the integer value prior to constructing your SQL as far as your database is concerned you'll just test the INT column for having a bit in the desired color flag position, like `WHERE ColorFlags & 8` where the 8 position corresponds to the color flag for the criteria.  I've added a link to my answer to a page that has a more comprehensive example.

Comment: @Tahbaza Ah, I see!  Thanks for the explanation.  This would be a pretty interesting way to do things.

Comment: @Kamil Szot Any stats on this?  I'm curious about how it compares to, say, a greater than, less than, equals etc. comparison.

Comment: @hithere -  Greater than, less than, equals use indexes. To find records with certain bits set you have to first and/or value of this field of each record with appropriate bitmask, hence you can't use indexes and always do full table scan. Try it in query planner.

Comment: @Kamil Szot - That makes sense.  Thank you.  And when you say query planner, do you mean something like EXPLAIN SELECT?

Comment: @hithere - EXPLAIN should let you see this. By query planner I was referring to the tool I used for PostrgreSQL that could show me exactly how my query will be executed, which tables will be used, how and in what order they will be joined and what indexes will be used and at which stage to narrow down my search. I'm not sure if there are such tools for MySQL.